# Proper way to handle complex querystrings in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, query-string

I'm somewhat new to MVC3 and I'm building a JSON API which must accept complex querystring arguments... here is an example

```
?filter[filters][0][value]=MyValue
```

Now if I just had something like

```
?MyParam=1
```

then I could just have a controller action like

```
public ActionResult SomeController(int MyParam) {}
```

But I don't know how to deal with the function arguments when there are apparent arrays and such.

What's the appropriate way to deal with this?

Comment: What? Why would you do that?  Could you provide more context?  If you're just doing arrays, MVC will take care of it fine out of the box.

Comment: It's a requirement of the javascript framework I am using. It's beyond my control.

Comment: Ahh. Ok.  I assumed it was something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at the following link. This helped me when I was trying to do the same:

[Haack - Model Binding to a List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)